# Woocommerce: Using a shortcode as product image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I tried to come up with a soulution for my problem but was not able to find one.
My problem is, that I try to use a [shortcode] as a product image in woocommerce. 
is there a easy way to do that or is this simply not possible with woocommerce?

Comment: Did you [define](https://codex.wordpress.org/it:Riferimento_funzioni/add_shortcode) your new 'shortcode'?

Comment: l got my shortcode from a plugin I installed and want to use it as the product image for a product.

Comment: I think you will have to edit some core php files.. This is not possible just from the backend